# Short story with carved amber figurines that animate and have an adventure, medieval in nature

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the name and author, of a certain golden age or slightly later, short story from a published hard back sci-fi anthology. It was more in the genre of sci-fi fantasy, about a carved amber figurine, about the size of a chess piece. I believe there was more than one carved figurine. They animate and have an adventure, medieval in nature, I think. The anthology was probably published in the '60's-'70's.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154760/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely be the answer as it doesn't meet the requirements of having been published in the 60's-70's... but there are some overlaps with your stated requirements with the Roger Zelazny short story "Blue Horse, Dancing Mountains", which appears in a posthumous collection entitled *Manna from Heaven*. It is set in the context of his *Chronicles of Amber* books which appeared in two sets of five, one in the 70s and one in the 80s. The first set is mostly medieval, while the second has more of a "cyberpunk" aesthetic. Here is a summary of the story taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manna_from_Heaven):

> Corwin flees the Courts of Chaos through a part of Shadow called the Dancing Mountains, having been given a new steed - a sentient shapechanger named Shask - as a gift by his son Merlin. *He eavesdrops on a game of chess between Dworkin and Suhuy* [ed: emphasis mine] and learns he has an appointment at the Hall of Mirrors in Amber Castle.

One of the chess pieces controlled by the character Dworkin is Castle Amber.

Comment: I've removed some of the commentary from the post and added the link for the quote, in future can you provide the link? Also worth noting people can be very poor at estimating dates, I've seen some be out be decades.

Comment: Certainly! And thank you for your effort. (My grimacing commentary on the use of the word 'cyberpunk' came from having seen it used as a common description of the books--but I myself do not use that word on a regular basis and did not want to misappropriate.)